# How can I add an empty page to this PDF document generated using iText?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I am working on some iText code written in the past by someone else and I have the following problem.

This is a method that create a page containing some information. I simply have to add a new empty page after this page but it seems not work (I still obtain the original infomration page).

So I have this code:

```
public ByteArrayOutputStream stampaTestataFatturaPdf(Fattura fattura) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream currentFatturaHeaderPdf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    // STEP 1 Creazione del documento in formato A4 e senza margini:
    com.itextpdf.text.Document document = new com.itextpdf.text.Document(com.itextpdf.text.PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    float fntSize = 10f;

    try {
        /* STEP 2 Constructs a PdfWriter.
                  document: The PdfDocument that has to be written.
                  os: The OutputStream the writer has to write to
         */

        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, currentFatturaHeaderPdf);

        // STEP 3:
        document.open();

        // STEP 4:

        // TABELLA MITTENTE:
        // La lunghezza e la larghezza sono invertite perchè la cella della tabella è ruotata di 90°:
        float lunghezza_mit = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.millimetersToPoints(35);      // 3,5 cm
        float altezza_mit = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.millimetersToPoints(70);        // 7 cm

        PdfPTable mittenteTable = new PdfPTable(1); // 1 columns.
        mittenteTable.setTotalWidth(lunghezza_mit);

        PdfContentByte canvasMittente = writer.getDirectContent();

        canvasMittente.setColorStroke(BaseColor.WHITE);

        PdfPCell cell1Mittente = new PdfPCell();

        Phrase mittente = new Phrase(fattura.getMittente(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
        Phrase indirizzoMittenteSection1 = new Phrase(fattura.getIndirizzoMittente(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
        Phrase indirizzoMittenteSection2 = new Phrase(fattura.getComuneMittente() + " " + fattura.getCapMittente() + " (" + fattura.getProvinciaMittente() + ")", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
        Phrase partitaIvaMittente = new Phrase(fattura.getPartivaIVAMittente(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
        Phrase telFax = new Phrase("Tel: " + fattura.getTelMittente() + " Fax:" + fattura.getFaxMittente(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));

        cell1Mittente.addElement(mittente);
        cell1Mittente.setBorderColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
        cell1Mittente.addElement(indirizzoMittenteSection1);
        cell1Mittente.addElement(indirizzoMittenteSection2);
        cell1Mittente.addElement(partitaIvaMittente);
        cell1Mittente.addElement(telFax);

        cell1Mittente.setRotation(90);
        cell1Mittente.setFixedHeight(altezza_mit);

        mittenteTable.addCell(cell1Mittente);

        float shift_x1_mitt = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.millimetersToPoints(15);     // 1,5 cm
        float shift_y1_mitt = altezza_mit + com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.millimetersToPoints(85);     // 8,5 cm

        mittenteTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, shift_x1_mitt, shift_y1_mitt, canvasMittente);


        // TABELLA DESTINATARIO:
        // La lunghezza e la larghezza sono invertite perchè la cella della tabella è ruotata di 90°:
        float lunghezza_dest = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.millimetersToPoints(45);      // 4,5 cm
        float altezza_dest = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.millimetersToPoints(95);        // 9,5 cm

        PdfPTable destinatarioTable = new PdfPTable(1); // 1 columns.
        destinatarioTable.setTotalWidth(lunghezza_dest);

        PdfContentByte canvasDestinatario = writer.getDirectContent();

        //PdfPCell cell1Destinatario = new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("DESTINATARIO"));
        PdfPCell cell1Destinatario = new PdfPCell();

        Phrase spettabile = new Phrase("Spett.le", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
        Phrase destinatario = new Phrase(commonUtility.gestioneCaratteriSpeciali(fattura.getDestinatario()), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
        Phrase indirizzoDestinatarioSection1 = new Phrase(commonUtility.gestioneCaratteriSpeciali(fattura.getIndirizzoDestinatario()), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));

        Phrase indirizzoDestinatarioSection2;
        if (fattura.getProvinciaDestinatario() != null) {

            if (nazionalitaFatturaCorrente.equals("E")) {  // Formattazione dell'indirizzo per le fatture estere
                indirizzoDestinatarioSection2 = new Phrase(commonUtility.gestioneCaratteriSpeciali((fattura.getCapDestinatario() != null ? fattura.getCapDestinatario() : "") + fattura.getComuneDestinatario()) + " (" + fattura.getProvinciaDestinatario() + ")", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
            } else {   // Formattazione dell'indirizzo per le fatture italiane
                indirizzoDestinatarioSection2 = new Phrase(commonUtility.gestioneCaratteriSpeciali(fattura.getComuneDestinatario()) + " " + (fattura.getCapDestinatario() != null ? fattura.getCapDestinatario() : "") + " (" + fattura.getProvinciaDestinatario() + ")", FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
            }

        } else {
            if (nazionalitaFatturaCorrente.equals("E")) {    // Formattazione dell'indirizzo per le fatture estere
                indirizzoDestinatarioSection2 = new Phrase(commonUtility.gestioneCaratteriSpeciali((fattura.getCapDestinatario() != null ? fattura.getCapDestinatario() : "") + " " + fattura.getComuneDestinatario()), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
            } else {      // Formattazione dell'indirizzo per le fatture italiane
                indirizzoDestinatarioSection2 = new Phrase(commonUtility.gestioneCaratteriSpeciali(fattura.getComuneDestinatario()) + " " + (fattura.getCapDestinatario() != null ? fattura.getCapDestinatario() : ""), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
            }
        }

        //Phrase pIvaDestinatario = new Phrase("P.I.: " + fattura.getPartivaIVADestinatario(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));
        Phrase codiceNazione = new Phrase(fattura.getCodiceNazione(), FontFactory.getFont(FontFactory.COURIER, fntSize));

        cell1Destinatario.addElement(spettabile);
        cell1Destinatario.addElement(destinatario);
        cell1Destinatario.setBorderColor(BaseColor.WHITE);
        cell1Destinatario.addElement(indirizzoDestinatarioSection1);
        cell1Destinatario.addElement(indirizzoDestinatarioSection2);

        if (fattura.getCodiceNazione() != null) {
            cell1Destinatario.addElement(codiceNazione);
        }

        cell1Destinatario.setRotation(90);
        cell1Destinatario.setFixedHeight(altezza_dest);

        destinatarioTable.addCell(cell1Destinatario);

        float shift_x1_dest = com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.millimetersToPoints(47);     // 4,7 cm
        float shift_y1_dest = altezza_dest + com.itextpdf.text.Utilities.millimetersToPoints(171);     // 17,1 cm

        destinatarioTable.writeSelectedRows(0, -1, shift_x1_dest, shift_y1_dest, canvasDestinatario);


        // TEST:
        document.newPage();
        Phrase testPhrase = new Phrase("TEST");
        document.add(testPhrase);


        // STEP 5:
        document.close();

    } catch (DocumentException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    return currentFatturaHeaderPdf;


}
```

This is pretty long but the interesting section is at the end of this method, infact, before close my document, I try to add a new page by this code:

```
// TEST:
document.newPage();
Phrase testPhrase = new Phrase("TEST");
document.add(testPhrase);
```

As you can see I am try to create new page at the document but it don't appear into my final generated PDF.

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix it and add this page?

Thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Make sure that you are using an official version of iText. In the official iText, the word "TEST" is added in similar cases. Providing a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) would help.

Comment: What do you mean with an "offivial version of iText"? exist also not official version?

Comment: I am using itext-1.3.jar maybe the problem could be that this is an old version?

Comment: iText 1.3 dates from [April 6, 2005](http://itextpdf.com/changelog/13). Why would you use a version that is more than 10 years old? That version is no longer supported. There are also some versions of iText that are distributed by people unknown to iText Group NV, which is the owner of the IP and Trademark of iText. Please use one of the most recent official versions (see http://itextpdf.com for more info).

Comment: @BrunoLowagie because I am working on a sickly very old legacy project and I can't change it to avoid the risk of impact in some other points. By the way I have solved my issue using an alternative way...this is not clean but it works...in this project nothing is clean :-/